# Find next input

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I need to get the next input to put the cursor on it after filling the first input. Help, please, if not difficult!

jQuery:

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val().match(/^\d{1}$/)){
    $(this).next('input').focus();
  }else{
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="block">
  <li><span data-tooltip="tooltip">text</span><input type="text"></li>
  <li><span data-tooltip="tooltip1">text1</span><input type="text"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Which part exactly isn't working as you expect - the listeners, the regex, the DOM traversal, something else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.next()` refers to the immediately adjacent (next) element, which is not true of your inputs.

Instead, try:

```
if($(this).val().match(/^\d{1}$/)){
  $(this).closest("li").next("li").find("input").focus();
}
```

`.closest("li")` traverses upwards until it finds an `<li>`. We then get the next `<li>` with `.next()`. Finally, we can dig in that `<li>` for an `input` using `.find("input")`

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!
$(this).closest("li").next("li").find("input").focus();